# Iterate over list of tuples

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I would really appreciate some input on my question - can't seem to make it work. I need to iterate over a list of tuples such as:

```
li = [('a',1),('b',2),('c', 2),('d', 2), ('e', 3), ('f', 3), ('g', 1)]
```

and would like to get a result such as:

```
new_li = [('a', 1), ('bcd',2), ('ef',3), ('g',1)]
```

where I concatenate strings based on the second value in the tuple. I do not want to use `groupby` from `itertools` because even though `g` is associated with `1`, it is not immediately next to `a`.
Thank you for all of the responses!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `itertools.groupby` - doesn't `[("".join([y[0] for y in list(g)]), x) for x, g in groupby(li, key=lambda x: x[1])]` produce the output you want?

Comment: Yea groupby only groups sequential values that are similar. @pault you should post that

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to keep `a` and `g` separate, then you want exactly what `groupby` does?

Comment: Thank you @AndreyTyukin, @pault. That's exactly what I wanted - I misunderstood how `groupby` works but now it's much clearer!

Answer (score 8):

IIUC, you *can* use `itertools.groupby` as it groups sequentially:

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby
new_li = [
    ("".join(y[0] for y in g), x) for x, g in groupby(li, key=lambda x: x[1])
]
print(new_li)
#[('a', 1), ('bcd', 2), ('ef', 3), ('g', 1)]
```

The keyfunc for the `groupby` gets the number from each tuple. Then for each group, you can join the letters together using `str.join`.

Comment: With `from itertools import itemgetter` you could replace `lambda x: x[1]` by `itemgetter(1)`. Admittedly, not much shorter in this case...

Answer (score 2):

From your description why you don't want to use `groupby` I've inferred that you actually want `a` and `g` grouped together. So maybe try this:

```
li = [('a',1),('b',2),('c', 2),('d', 2), ('e', 3), ('f', 3), ('g', 1)]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for c,i in li:
  d[i].append(c)

new_li = [(''.join(cs), i) for (i, cs) in d.items()]

print(new_li)
# output: [('ag', 1), ('bcd', 2), ('ef', 3)]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if this is the desired output you could also just apply `itertools.groupby` on `sorted(li, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))`

Comment: @pault The above solution is `O(N)`. The `sorted` is `O(N log N)`. I don't like the fact that the unusual interface provided by `groupby` forces me to use an `O(N log N)` sorting that I don't really need. But yeah, one could also use `sorted`. By the way, this time, `itemgetter(1,0)` would definitely be shorter ;)

Comment: I forgot you can pass multiple args to `itemgetter`!